# How to get numeric keypad on qooxdoo mobile textfield widget

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a textfield widget in a qooxdoo mobile app which is intended for numeric input only.

Is there any way to get a numeric keypad when inputting/editing values on a qooxdoo mobile textfield widget?

I have found this http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html .

That link would be a solution if I knew how to access the html input element of the textfield widget that I could set the type and step attributes on it. But maybe qooxdoo offers a more direct solution.

So the question is - how to get a numeric keypad when inputting/editing to a qooxdoo mobile textfield widget.

Answer (score 0):

There exists qooxdoo.ui.mobile.form.NumberField which has a very attractive numeric keypad.

Does the job very nicely.

Hope this helps someone else.